# Can you use NSPredicate to place a fetched item before all others when using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am pulling sorted `Friend` objects out of my data store that match a given `User` as part of a `NSFetchedResultsController` that drives a `UICollectionView` As shown below;

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedFriendsResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedFriendsResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedFriendsResultsController;
    }

    //Get the correct array of friends for that user
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestItems = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityItem = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Friend" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequestItems setEntity:entityItem];

    User* myUser = [DataBaseManager getCurrentUser:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequestItems setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@", myUser]];

    //Sort by name descending
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequestItems setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedItemsResultsController =[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequestItems managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    _fetchedFriendsResultsController = fetchedItemsResultsController;

    return _fetchedFriendsResultsController;
}
```

This works fine and all friends are sorted alphabetically descending.

Now i want to take a specific friend object, that has a name that isn't alphabetically first in order of precedence, and place them ahead of all other friend items in the returned. Make a special case for them where 'name' == @"SPECIFIC_NAME".

Do i need to add this edge case to the sort descriptor or the Predicate ? And how would you do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you need a further `attribute` and a further `sortDescriptor`.

if this `friend` is something special, show it with an attribute like `isSpecial` and add as first `sortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"isSpecial" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
[fetchRequestItems setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: I see your point, but the issue here is i want to make a binary comparison between say "name == specificName" without having to modify my data model. This works though, if i cant find a more concise solution ill go with this.

Comment: So i will add a new flag to my friend object and migrate my data store to handle this addition. Not sure what the overheads here are on efficiency so i will leave the question open for a few hours to see what other suggestions pop up.